# libpthreads.so missing in Ubuntu 21.10 (amd64)

Tags: system-installation

I tried to locate `libpthread.so` but it only gave me:

```
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
```

I then installed it with:

```
sudo apt-get install libpthread-stubs0-dev
```

But still, no `libpthread.so`. Please, can someone help?

Comment: What is the actual problem you are trying to solve here? If you are trying to build a program using POSIX threads with gcc, you should probably be using your compiler's `-pthread` option rather than explicitly linking against `libpthread`. See for example [Difference between -pthread and -lpthread while compiling](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62561519/4440445)

Answer (score 8):

Just faced the same issue. One quick workaround is to make a symlink:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so
```

Comment: But why are those links missing? Manually doing things in /usr/lib is not a good idea so the actual cause and solution would be nice.