# installing ovito on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: make

I am new to Ubuntu, so I tried to install ovito based on: https://www.ovito.org/manual/development/build_linux.html
After executing the final step which is (cmake --build . --parallel), I encounter this error:

```
[379/846] Linking CXX shared library lib/ovito/plugins/Mesh.so
FAILED: lib/ovito/plugins/Mesh.so 
: && /usr/bin/c++ -fPIC -O3 -DNDEBUG  -Wl,-O2 -Wl,--sort-common -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,--disable-new-dtags -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,-rpath,/home/latif/anaconda3/lib -Wl,-rpath-link,/home/latif/anaconda3/lib -L/home/latif/anaconda3/lib   -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,--no-allow-shlib-undefined -shared -Wl,-soname,Mesh.so -o lib/ovito/plugins/Mesh.so src/ovito/mesh/CMakeFiles/Mesh.dir/Mesh_autogen/mocs_compilation.cpp.o src/ovito/mesh/CMakeFiles/Mesh.dir/surface/SurfaceMesh.cpp.o src/ovito/mesh/CMakeFiles/Mesh.dir/surface/SurfaceMeshAccess.cpp.o src/ovito/mesh/CMakeFiles/Mesh.dir/surface/RenderableSurfaceMesh.cpp.o src/ovito/mesh/CMakeFiles/Mesh.dir/surface/SurfaceMeshVis.cpp.o src/ovito/mesh/CMakeFiles/Mesh.dir/surface/SurfaceMeshTopology.cpp.o src/ovito/mesh/CMakeFiles/Mesh.dir/surface/SurfaceMeshVertices.cpp.o src/ovito/mesh/CMakeFiles/Mesh.dir/surface/SurfaceMeshFaces.cpp.o src/ovito/mesh/CMakeFiles/Mesh.dir/surface/SurfaceMeshRegions.cpp.o src/ovito/mesh/CMakeFiles/Mesh.dir/io/VTKFileImporter.cpp.o src/ovito/mesh/CMakeFiles/Mesh.dir/io/VTKTriangleMeshExporter.cpp.o src/ovito/mesh/CMakeFiles/Mesh.dir/io/ParaViewVTPMeshImporter.cpp.o src/ovito/mesh/CMakeFiles/Mesh.dir/io/ParaViewVTRSimulationCellImporter.cpp.o src/ovito/mesh/CMakeFiles/Mesh.dir/io/ParaViewVTUSimulationCellImporter.cpp.o src/ovito/mesh/CMakeFiles/Mesh.dir/io/ParaViewVTMImporter.cpp.o src/ovito/mesh/CMakeFiles/Mesh.dir/io/ParaViewPVDImporter.cpp.o src/ovito/mesh/CMakeFiles/Mesh.dir/io/WavefrontOBJImporter.cpp.o src/ovito/mesh/CMakeFiles/Mesh.dir/io/STLImporter.cpp.o src/ovito/mesh/CMakeFiles/Mesh.dir/util/polytess/dict.c.o src/ovito/mesh/CMakeFiles/Mesh.dir/util/polytess/geom.c.o src/ovito/mesh/CMakeFiles/Mesh.dir/util/polytess/memalloc.c.o src/ovito/mesh/CMakeFiles/Mesh.dir/util/polytess/mesh.c.o src/ovito/mesh/CMakeFiles/Mesh.dir/util/polytess/normal.c.o src/ovito/mesh/CMakeFiles/Mesh.dir/util/polytess/priorityq.c.o src/ovito/mesh/CMakeFiles/Mesh.dir/util/polytess/render.c.o src/ovito/mesh/CMakeFiles/Mesh.dir/util/polytess/sweep.c.o src/ovito/mesh/CMakeFiles/Mesh.dir/util/polytess/tess.c.o src/ovito/mesh/CMakeFiles/Mesh.dir/util/polytess/tessmono.c.o -L/home/latif/anaconda3/lib/gcc/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/7.3.0   -L/home/latif/anaconda3/lib/gcc   -L/home/latif/anaconda3/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/lib   -L/home/latif/anaconda3/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/sysroot/lib   -L/home/latif/anaconda3/x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu/sysroot/usr/lib -Wl,-rpath,/home/latif/ovito/build/lib/ovito/plugins:/home/latif/ovito/build/lib/ovito:  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt6Gui.so.6.2.4  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt6Xml.so.6.2.4  lib/ovito/plugins/StdObj.so  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX.so  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOpenGL.so  lib/ovito/plugins/Core.so  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt6Gui.so.6.2.4  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX.so  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOpenGL.so  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt6Network.so.6.2.4  /home/latif/anaconda3/lib/libz.so  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt6Gui.so.6.2.4  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX.so  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOpenGL.so  lib/ovito/libovito_muparser.so  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt6Core.so.6.2.4  -pthread && :
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find /lib/libpthread.so.0: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find /usr/lib/libpthread_nonshared.a: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
[380/846] Automatic MOC for target Gui
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Thanks for any help to resolve this issue.

Comment: `cannot find /lib/libpthread.so.0`  Install that?  This one seems the same https://askubuntu.com/questions/1369437/libpthreads-so-missing-in-ubuntu-21-10-amd64 though worded differently.

Comment: actually I located the libthread.so.0 ad.so.0

also, I ran the command sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so
the output is: ln: failed to create symbolic link '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so': File exists

Comment: add it to the q. I will delete my comment after you did.

Comment: Hi, since I am new to this I have no clue what do you mean, please enlighten me. thanks. Also, this is the link for the resolved issue: https://www.ovito.org/forum/topic/ovito-install-error-on-ubuntu-22-04/#postid-4132